# Selecting Cesium entities through HTML elements

Tags: cesiumjs

Is it possible to select Cesium entities created on the Cesium viewer and select them through HTML elements, for example a button? Or is it possible to select them only through the viewer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to select them from code. Assign `viewer.selectedEntity` to the desired entity.  You may also assign `viewer.trackedEntity` to zoom to the entity and follow it with the camera.

Here's a [Sandcastle Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

```js
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  shouldAnimate: true,
});

Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load("../SampleData/simple.czml").then(function(dataSource) {
  viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
  
  var iss = dataSource.entities.getById("Satellite/ISS");
  var agi = dataSource.entities.getById("Facility/AGI");
  
  Sandcastle.addDefaultToolbarButton("Select ISS", function () {
    viewer.selectedEntity = iss;
  });

  Sandcastle.addDefaultToolbarButton("Select AGI", function () {
    viewer.selectedEntity = agi;
  });

  Sandcastle.addDefaultToolbarButton("Deselect", function () {
    viewer.selectedEntity = undefined;
  });

});
```